# AVPlayer pause video when leaving view.

Tags: video, avplayer, pause

Has anyone figured out how to pause AVPlayer when exiting a view? I have searched everywhere and found no answers.

I tried adding the "player pause" func in the viewWillDissappear and viewDidDisappear. Neither one seem to get it. Don't know if it has something to do will the scroll view but there seems there should be a way. Didn't see anything in Apple documentation either.

Here is what I have tried.

```
//
 //  VideoTestViewController.swift
//  Faces of the Holocaust Photographic History
//
//  Created by New User on 8/26/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 New User. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit



class VideoTest: UIViewController {


var player : AVPlayer?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url : URL = URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/faces-of-the-holocaust.appspot.com/o/Alan%20Hall.mp4?alt=media&token=19c13572-b6fb-42e9-94e5-535dac227de5")!
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer?
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
    playerLayer!.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view!.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
    player.play()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool){

player?.pause()
}
*/

@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    let playerIsPlaying = player?.rate != 0
    if playerIsPlaying {
        player?.pause()
    } else {
        player?.play()
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you have to use viewDidDisappear instead of viewWillDisappear